# Number formatting with awk

Tags: awk, number-formatting

I have several files with many columns and thousands of lines. Most entries are float with too high precision and some are given in scientific notation. I am trying to use awk to reformat all the numbers but I am not very familiar with awk. I have tried the following

```
cat bs04_diff_all_e.csv | awk -v OFS="," -v OFMT="%.2f" -F"," 'NR == 45 {printf $1,$2,$3,$4,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19}'
```

Which outputs

```
648376.819998
```

only. i.e. the first post in the line, unformatted.

```
cat bs04_diff_all_e.csv | awk -v OFS="," -v OFMT="%.2f" -F"," 'NR == 45 {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19}'
```

outputs

```
648376.819998,7537575.31999,1692.0,34.99202,0.30931,0.0054,0.07764,0.01284,0.00849,0.04081,0.0403,0.00946,-9e-05
```

So there I get the columns but the formatting is still not working. I have looked around for a solution and cannot see why this doesn't work but then as I stated earlier, I am not familiar with awk. What am I doing wrong? Do I really have to specify the number format for all 44 columns individually?

Comment: Please add some sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: +1 for the OFMT, I wasn't aware of it. Also, instead of `cat file | awk ...`, you can directly do `awk ... file`.

Comment: Well, the last line of output is basically the input, minus some columns. It's a csv file with a row of headers, 44 columns and thousands of rows. As you can see, the precision and format varies but the data looks like the line near the bottom of the post. My expected output would be all the the numbers given in float to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `OFMT` variable and use `sprintf()` using a format string before the variables. Last `END {}` section removes the trailing comma:

```
cat bs04_diff_all_e.csv | 
    awk -F"," '
        BEGIN { split("1,2,3,4,11", l, /,/) } 
        { for (i in l) { s = s sprintf( "%.2f,", $(l[i]) ) } }
        END { sub(/,$/, "\n", s); print s }
    '
```

It yields something like:

```
648376.82,7537575.32,1692.00,34.99,0.04
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get awk: calling undefined function strtonum

Comment: @mercergeoinfo: I've edited the post to use `sprintf()` instead.

Comment: Sorry but there must be an error somewhere, awk just sits and waits for something more. I've tried extra ' but that didn't help

Comment: @mercergeoinfo: It works in my shell. Try to solve it by yourself, join all the script in one line. Or add the first line, when it works, add the second one and so on. I can't help you with it because I cannot reproduce it. At least I need more information.

Comment: I tried putting it all on one line but the problem is the same, it just sits there waiting. I'll try solving this in Python. I've spent approximately 5 hours on this already, I need to move on, if only for my sanity's sake.